# How to add key/values dynamically to your Info.plist?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, info.plist

To add any keys and values we'll add them by adding source code or through the property section(where we can choose permissions and can add their text).

Now, I want them to be dynamically added. Basically, I have permissions settings inside the admin web application from where we can control the permissions we need to add to our mobile application.

My requirement::
I need to add keys/values through some variables, is it possible? Basically need to generate the keys from the permissions user allowed inside permission settings.

In info.plist, I would like to add the following permission through some variables:

```
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>YOUR TEXT</string>
```

Also, if it is impossible to add dynamic keys/values, what should I do to update my info.plist?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot edit your `Info.plist` at runtime. It's shipped as part of your app's bundle, and your bundle is read-only. You must have your `Info.plist` configured how you want it to be at compile time

Comment: What if I just need to update the code of info.plist, I don't need to update this on runtime. Like when we perform linking it adds code to info.plist and removes it if we unlink. My requirement is similar. I want to add code if we enable any permission from the admin and remove it if it is disabled.

Comment: You'd probably be best off writing your own script to do that

Answer (score 0):

The Cordova documentation for the Camera plugin, under iOS Quirks, says to place this information in the config.xml file, within the widget element.

```
<edit-config target="NSCameraUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
    <string>need camera access to take pictures</string>
</edit-config>
```

This is the config.xml file at the root of your cordova project.

You will then need to rebuild for iOS

```
> cordova build ios
```

Be aware that this will rebuild your project using the information in the root www folder.  If you, like me, have been editing the files under the platform/ios folder, copy those files back to the root www folder before you rebuild your project.